# How can I run one sampler continuously

Tags: jmeter

In our website one broadcasting runs for 10 seconds. In 10 seconds, if it does not get response, then it again runs for next 10 seconds and it continues till it gets response. 
In jmeter, when I am recording the script, that Broadcasting sampler gets recorded only once but while running the script, it does not show response as it does not get that in single run. Can anyone help me to know how to script in jmeter for that broadcasting sampler to run until it gets the response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the While Controller, where you configure your script to run until get response.

More information, look at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller